# FLVPlayback Resizing?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

Alright, so I'm playing several different videos at different sizes with the FLVPlayback component and something odd is happening that I don't remember happening before...

Now, when I switch from video to video, the FLVPlayback physically resizes to match the height of the video... I don't remember this happening before. Before, the FLVPlayback would just vertical center the video no matter what size the height of the video is.

Am I missing something? It's really annoying that the FLVPlayback's height changes constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the scaleMode property in the component parameters.